# Jquery Unable to bind focus event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created an element using javascript and trying to bind focus/blur event, but it is not firing. How can I acheive the same?

```js
var parentContainer = document.getElementById('parent');
var container = document.createElement('div');
container.innerHTML = '<p>Hello</p>';
container.style.userSelect = "none";
container.style.MozUserSelect = "none";

parentContainer.appendChild(container);

$(container).focus(function () {
  $(this).css('border', '1px solid')
}).blur(function () {
  $(this).css('border', '')
});

//container.addEventListener('focus',function () {
//  $(this).css('border', '1px solid')
//})
//container.addEventListener('blur',function () {
//  $(this).css('border', '')
//})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='parent'>
  
</div>
```

Comment: You can't have `focus` and `blur` on elements which don't accept a focal point.  Do you mean `mouseover` and `mouseout`?  Also, you should use `.on("eventname", function` instead of `.eventname(function`

Comment: @freefaller I want to change the border of element on focus, and blur need to remove it. mouseover and mouseout won't work out here I guess.

Comment: But you **can't** put focus on an element that doesn't accept a focal point. You can focus on things like `<input>`, `<select>`, etc... but you can't focus on a `<div>`

Comment: @freefaller technically you can if you add a `tabindex` attribute, but it's not good practice for UX, and is a bit hacky.

Comment: @Rory - I did not know that... thanks for the information, and I stand corrected (but I totally agree, it's not nice)

Comment: Adding `tabIndex = -1` works in this case.

Answer (score 0):

In order to apply focus on div, you need to add tabindex to the div. I would suggest you use mouseover or hover to apply or do anything specific because the focus property should be used for input fields

```
<div id='parent' tabindex="100">

</div>
```